# RoboSpice Caching of Date Attributes in POJO Object-Issue in Serialization

Tags: android, robospice

The following is being shared for others that run into this issue....AND also for RoboSpice Cache experts out there who may have information on how this should best be handled.

I am using RoboSpice 1.4.5 for Android native development.  We implemented a pattern where we are using the cached request `POJO` objects.  Our `POJO` object has an attribute that is a `java.util.Date`.  Our initial data comes from web services implemented in Microsoft ASP.NET MVC4.  The initial JSON format for the Date is `/Date(number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970)/`

We had to implement a `CustomDateSerializer` class in order to get the Date objects to go into the RoboSpice Cache with a `Date` format that the later Deserializer would see as the same as what came from the original web service.

So in order to get caching to work... we had to implement:

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
  @Override
  public void serialize(Date arg0, JsonGenerator arg1, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    arg1.writeString("/Date(" + arg0.getTime() + ")/");
  }
}
```

Is this the correct fix / implementation ?